# How can I get the list of iOS root certificates in human readable form

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, root-certificate

I want to get the list of iOS trusted root certificate in human readable form. 
By writing code or any tools. How can I get that?

I tried with some code like the following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966969/enumerate-all-keychain-items-in-my-ios-application), but its return null. Status return -25300, which is item not found.

```
- (void) readCert2 {
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
//                                (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes,
                                (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnRef,
                                  (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit,
                                  nil];
    NSArray *secItemClasses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
//                             (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
//                             (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                               (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
//                             (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
//                             (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
                               nil];
    for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
        [query setObject:secItemClass forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

        CFTypeRef result = NULL;
        OSStatus status =  SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
        NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge id)result);
        if (result != NULL) CFRelease(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, its not possible yet upto the iOS 6.1.4 APIs. I have asked in apple forum and one of the apple developers answered so.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a list of the trusted root certificate on their web site.

- [iOS 5 and iOS 6: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012)
- [iOS 4.x: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4415)
- [iOS 2.x: List of Available Trusted Root Certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2185)

Comment: Those lists are quite old. And I need to read from the phone/pad in their existing keychain.