# How can I enumerate all Keychain items in my OS X application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, keychain, core-foundation

Please, help me resolve problem with enumerating keychain items in OS X. I read topic about [enumerating all keychain items in my iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966969/enumerate-all-keychain-items-in-my-ios-application/11672902#11672902), but a want understand, how write the same code, which written in the topic with Core Foundation functions??? I tried to do that:

```
CFDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreate ( kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
CFTypeRef *result = NULL;

status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, result );
if (status != errSecSuccess)
{
    GetLastError(status);
}
```

But this code didn't work! Could you help me understand, where I was wrong. Function "SecItemCopyMatching" returned error: **One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid.** Error code: -50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're providing an empty dictionary and not a valid query.

If you take the [code from the answer you were looking at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672902/981049) and drop it into your project:

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes,
                              (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit,
                              nil];

NSArray *secItemClasses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
                           nil];

for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
    [query setObject:secItemClass forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
    NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge id)result);
    if (result != NULL) CFRelease(result);
}
```

You'll have a happier result.

***EDITED to add the CoreFoundation equivalent***

There's no reason why you can't include the Cocoa framework in your MacOS command line tool (which is what I'm assuming you are writing).  What a command line tool can't easily include is the AppKit UI framework.

Anyways, here is the CoreFoundation equivalent:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0,
                                   &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                   &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);


CFDictionarySetValue(query, kSecReturnAttributes, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFDictionarySetValue(query, kSecMatchLimit, kSecMatchLimitAll);

CFTypeRef types[5];

types[0] = kSecClassGenericPassword;
types[1] = kSecClassInternetPassword;
types[2] = kSecClassCertificate;
types[3] = kSecClassKey;
types[4] = kSecClassIdentity;

CFArrayRef secItemClasses = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)types, 5, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
CFIndex i, c = CFArrayGetCount(secItemClasses);

for(i = 0; i<c; i++)
{
    CFTypeRef secItemClass = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(secItemClasses,i);
    CFDictionarySetValue(query, kSecClass, secItemClass);

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result);
    NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge id)result);
    if (result != NULL) CFRelease(result);
}

CFRelease(secItemClasses);
CFRelease(query);
```

When I put this into my own test app, I'm seeing quite a large dump of various keychain items and certificates.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But if I want to write application without Cocoa.framework, I should adaptive this code with CoreFoundation.framework. According with it, I answer, how can I modify that code? And then, how I can find my password and login from site?

Answer (score 1):

The OP did not ask about another keychain, but hopefully this will help future readers.

Michael's code is a simple way to show 'some' of the items stored in the keychain.  I discovered through much trial and error that his code will not return the iCloud keychain.  To see the iCloud keychain, add the key/value pair:

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes,
                              (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit,
                              //  added to find keychain items saved in iCloud
                              (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecAttrSynchronizable,
                              nil];
```

The query dictionary for `SecItemCopyMatching()` is important and little understood!

** Caveat:  This was tested on iPhone device, not on Mac.