# How to get list of keychains keys in my application

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am using this keychain wrapper to get and set keychain: https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

I cannot seem to find a way to iterate existing keys in the keychain in my app

Is there a way of doing this?

One solution I have in mind is to save all the saved keys in a plist and iterate that - which doesn't sound too good.

Comment: Have you seen this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966969/enumerate-all-keychain-items-in-my-ios-application ?

Comment: Hi @EvgenyKarkan thanks for your comment, unfortunately I am new to ios dev application and i started off with Swift - do you mind if you could write that in swift? Thanks

Comment: you can mix Swift and ObjC code in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all keys in your keychain using SecItemCopyMatching which will return one or more key items that match a search query, in this case using kSecMatchLimit will return all items that match the criteria and not just the first one found.
The method `getKeychainAccounts()` returns an array with all keys in your keychain.

```
func getKeychainAccounts() -> [String] {
    var accounts: [String] = []
    
    let query: [String: Any] = [
      kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
      kSecAttrService as String: yourServiceValue, // change this line to match your service account value 
      kSecReturnAttributes as String: true,
      kSecReturnData as String: true,
      kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll
    ]
            
    var result: CFTypeRef?
    let operationStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)
    
    let resultArray = result as! [NSDictionary]
    
    switch operationStatus {
        case errSecSuccess:
        resultArray.forEach { item in
            if let accountData = item[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? Data,
               let account = String(data: accountData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print("key: \(account)")
                accounts.append(account)
            }
            
        }
        default:
            print("No one item found")
        }
    return accounts
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching