# Not able to retrieve the certificate stored in keychain group/ keychain on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

I have a requirement wherein I have to import the certificate (SSL) stored in the device's keychain and use the same to perform SSL handshake with the server. I am basically distributing an enterprise App through Hockey SDK or Airwatch to the end users.

I'm exploring this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/identities/importing_an_identity?language=objc

Also, third party tools like
https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/10-2/swift/guide/using-secure-services.html

Need inputs on how to proceed ahead.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and tell us what do you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Shashanth ,

I am trying the following link :

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966969/enumerate-all-keychain-items-in-my-ios-application

Here, I have also tried with the following details
 [query setObject:@"XXXXXXX" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];
 [query setObject:@"XXXXXXX" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
  [query setObject:@"XXXXXXX" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
  [query setObject:@"XXXXXXX" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];

Comment: Shashanth any inputs?