# Swift 4 Get Keychain Data from Another Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, keychain

So I developed an iOS app called `Due it` a while back, and I had no idea what I was doing at the time. Anyhow, I lost all of the files for it, so i decided to re-create the project, but I stored data in Keychain on the old version. Is there any way that I can get the Keychain data back? (im using the same Bundle Identifier)

I've tried using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310869/4705065 but it doesnt find any data.

Comment: A side note, look into using some sort of git repository in an attempt to prevent that from happing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this point.

You are able to add multiple applications to a *Keychain Access Group* within an app, but you would have had to do that within the original app you no longer have access to.

[More information on Keychain Access Groups.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps)

It would be a big security concern if anyone could access anything within keychain without explicit permission.