# How to complete delete an iOS app data from keychain manully

Tags: ios, keychain, appdata, ios-app-group, ios-app-signing

I'm an test associate. Developers in my organisation have made a mistake in the code. After deleting the app, it leaves behind certain keychain data, which stops me from installing any other version of the app and testing it.
Let's take the error build as "X" and other build as "Y"
For X build alone i'm getting 200 response from charles proxy. For all other builds Charles proxy response shows 401 unauthorised for any other version of the app.
Is there a way to remove the app data from keychain?

Comment: Erase the device...

Comment: Can you talk to a friendly developer on your team?  I have had a similar issue with the keychain in other projects. The developers can create a standalone keychain cleaner for your app fairly quickly.

Comment: @WarrenBurton can you give me more detail on how the developer did that, so i can propose this solution in a better way..!

Comment: @vishal now I remember it wasn’t standalone. we had a QA/debug menu in the build with a “clear keychain” item among other things. The action would dump everything. E.g via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966969/enumerate-all-keychain-items-in-my-ios-application but it will depend on how your app devs implement the keychain support. This might be a harder thing to sell if you don’t have a QA / dev menu already. Good luck.